# How to get the last modified file based on a specific date and import to python script

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of files stored in my Data folder.  I can get `list_of_files`:

```
list_of_files = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Desktop\Data\*.csv')
```

I want to use pandas to read the last modified file on one specific date, say 05/31/2021. On 05/31/2021, there might be more than one files modified, and I need the last modified one `latest_file`, then import to python script like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(latest_file, usecols=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

How can I realize it? Many thanks

(Any solution for the previous part would be great. It would be even better if you can make the modified date be last day of a certain month, like 04/30/2021, 05/31/2021, 6/30/2021 etc.)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python) help?

Comment: It's not the same. I don't need the modified date. I need the file

Comment: And it is not last modified based on system time. I need the last modified based on a specific date

Answer (score 1):

I would like to thank Umar.H for helping me with this issue through a call. I attached my code below:

```
def get_latest_file(datetime: str, location: str) -> str:
    files = Path(location).glob('*.csv')

    file_df = pd.DataFrame({'path': files})

    file_df['mdate'] = pd.to_datetime(file_df['path'].apply(lambda x: x.stat().st_mtime), unit='s')

    try:
        idx = file_df.loc[
            (file_df['mdate'] >= pd.Timestamp(datetime))
            &
            (file_df['mdate'] < (pd.Timestamp(datetime)
                                 + pd.DateOffset(hours=23, minutes=59))
             )]['mdate'].idxmax()

        print(f"Returning file {file_df.loc[idx]['path'].stem} with a modify time of {file_df.loc[idx]['mdate']}")
        return file_df.loc[idx]['path']
    except (KeyError, FileNotFoundError):
        return ("No file matched the time delta.")


df4 = pd.read_csv(get_latest_file('28 May 2021', r'C:\Users\...\Desktop'])
```